# Editing ore/structure generation with NBTExplorer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I was wondering if there was a way to increase the spawn rate of ores and structures using NBTEditor. I've been able to change player data, spawn "illegal" enchanted items, and other fun things, but I haven't been able to find a way to change the way the map generates.

Is it even possible to edit the spawn rates of iron/copper/etc without downloading/creating mods? Only looking to either change chunks that either haven't been generated or on a brand new world.

Answer (score -1):

This was possible before 1.13 with use of the customized world generation setting, but has now been removed in favor of using data packs to change generation. To read more about creating data packs, read [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack) entry on the unofficial Minecraft wiki.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which would need an explanation of how to do this with data packs.